# tinyMce color palette size

Tags: tinymce

using tinyMce html editor control, I'm trying to limit the width in cols of the popup color picker, but setting color_cols doesn't seem to do anything.. am I missing something ?    it's a very simple config..

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: `#myTextarea`,
        promotion: false,
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar: 'fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor ', 
        color_cols: 5,
        color_map: [
            "000000", "Black",
            "434343", "Dove Gray",
            "666666", "Gray",
            "999999", "Spanish Gray",
            "b7b7b7", "Gray (X11)",
            "cccccc", "Light Gray",
            "d9d9d9", "Gainsboro",
             ...... (I have about 40 colors)
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it, the color_cols option doesn't work, you have to specify the option for foreground and background separately.

```
color_cols_foreground: 10,
color_cols_background: 10,
```